# SQL: How to multiply a cell by a column that contains specific text

Tags: sql

My data looks like this:

```
Currency  Price  FX_Rate_MXN  FX_Rate_BRL
MXN       $5     .2           .5
BRL       $7     .2           .5
```

I'd like to create a new column that will multiply "Price" by the correct exchange rate, depending on the currency in the "Currency" column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when currency = 'MX' then price * fx_rate_mxn
             when currency = 'BRL' then price * fx_rate_brl
        end) as price_in_currency
from t;
```

Of course, it is not clear if you want to multiply or divide by the fx rate.